Slater-Koster tables
The Slater-Koster tables are an important tool to do calculations within the LCAOformalism and in this problem we explore their significance. Consider two atomic orbitals centered at $\vec x_1=(0,0,0)^T$ and $\vec x_2=(R,0,0)^T$ We assume that the atomic orbital in position $\vec x_1$ is written as $\phi_1(\vec x)=R_1(x)p_\alpha(\vec x)$ and $\phi_2(\vec x)=R_1(x)p_\beta(\vec x)$. When $\alpha=\beta=x$ i.e the lobes point towards each other- we call the matrix element of the Hamiltonian $V_{p,p,\sigma}$. Whereas for the case $\alpha=\beta=y$ or $\alpha=\beta=z$
i.e. parallel lobes we call the matrix element  $V_{p,p,\pi}$
Consider two $p_x$-like orbitals one of them centered again at $\vec x_1=(0,0,0)^T$ but the other one centered at $\vec R=(Rcos\phi,Rsin\phi,0)^T$
Express the matrix element between these two orbitals in terms of $V_{p,p,\pi}$ and $V_{p,p,\sigma}$. One can assume that whenever the lobes point towards each other the matrix element is $V_{p,p,\sigma}p,p,\sigma$ and whenever the lobes are parallel the matrix element is $V_{p,p,\sigma}p,p,\pi$.
Hint: Introduce a coordinate system with $x′$-axis along $\vec R$ and express the coordinates x, y and z in the original coordinate system by $x′$, $y′$ and $z′$ in the rotated one. This allows to express any function of $x$, $y$ and $z$ as function of $x′$, $y′$ and $z′$ ...
I am trying to understand how exactly the shift in coordinate frame ease our problem.
If I rotate the coordinate system so that $x'$ aligns with $\vec R$ my $p_x$ orbitals are not aligned with $x'$.
Can someone help me understand the goal here? I am very confused


You should write down relevant text. Copying whole pages like that counts as copyvio, I think.

I changed it accordingly. Thank you for letting me know

The goal? The given matrix elements are when the line joining the centres is coincident with the x axis. Your mission, should you coose to accept it, is to find the matrix elements for when this is not the case, expressing your answer in terms of the x axis ones. In other words you need to perform a rotation

@IanBush But if I perform a rotation aren't I essentially lining them along the new x' axis? I am confused here
